# REST design best practices for adding and deleting multiple objects simultaneously

Tags: java, api, rest, api-design

I would like to know how to handle both addition and deletion in a list using REST. Here's an example object which I want to change.

```
{
    name: SomeName
    id: 1
    email: [foo@foo.com, bar@bar.com]
}
```

The user should be allowed to update the email list where he/she can add an email address and remove an email address at the same time.

The API is `PATCH /{id}` 
 
I can think of two ways to achieve this

1. The user passes the complete email list every-time which is updated. However, the problem I can think of with this approach is if 2 people simultaneously update the email, some updates might be lost. 
    Example User 1 wants to remove foo and add foo1 `email: [foo1@foo1.com, bar@bar.com]`, whereas user 2 wants to remove bar and add bar1 `email: [foo@foo.com, bar1@bar1.com]`. Here whichever request is processed later that particular data would be stored whereas the desired result should be `email: [foo1@foo1.com, bar1@bar1.com]`
2. Another approach would be to take removed and added email addresses separately in the API. That is, have 2 fields `email_addresses_to_add` and `email_addresses_to_remove`. 
   As in the example above, User 1 would send 
   `{email_addresses_to_remove:[foo@foo.com], email_addresses_to_add:[foo1@foo1.com]}` 
   User 2 would send `{email_addresses_to_remove:[bar@bar.com], email_addresses_to_add:[bar1@bar1.com]}`

What would be the correct way to achieve this so that concurrent updates are handled gracefully? Is the 2nd approach correct? Or is there a better way?

Comment: Another approach is to have separate endpoints.  From the user perspective, they might be pressing a single button, but the back-end could make 2 calls (1 to create the new email and 1 to remove an old email).  This will avoid collisions with another concurrent user.  Making 2 calls will obviously be slower, but those 2 calls be done concurrently.

Comment: Another approach is to notify the other user the resource has been updated (callbacks, webhooks, topics, websockets, etc.), and update the other user's UI, along with their pending changes.

Comment: Another approach is to return a resource token when the resource is fetched.  When submitting an update, the token must be included in the request.  If the submitted token matches the actual resource token, then the update is allowed, and a new token is assigned as part of updating the resource.  The other user attempts an update and is blocked since the other user submitted an old token.  This is easier than updating the other user's UI mentioned in my other comment, and might be acceptable if resource collisions are expected to be rare.

Answer (score 0):

In HTTP, the most straight foward way to deal with this would be to allow the client to edit the representation direction, and then send back a complete copy of the new document with [PUT](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.4).

PATCH is normally only interesting when the document is large in comparison to the HTTP headers, and the changes are small relative to the size of the document.

---

But if you must use PATCH, because reasons, then you should be sending a patch-document.  The precise nature of how to describe the edits you are making will depend on which patch format the client decides to use.

If what you have here is a JSON document, then you've got some interesting standardized options.  [JSON Patch](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6902) (application/json-patch+json) and JSON Merge Patch (application/merge-patch+json) would be the first two to look at.

---

If you have multiple authors trying to modify the same resource, then you will probably want to look into [Conditional Requests](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7232), which gives clients a convenient way to identify the representation of the resource that they received (prior to applying their own local edits).

Answer (score 0):

The correct way exists, but it's quite sophisticated.
First, you need to introduce revisions of the data — to know exactly what a person changing the list were looking at.
Second, you need to consider each operation (adding, deleting, moving) being an atomic action, like that:

```
{
   "action": "delete",
   "position": 1
}
```

Third, you need to make clients send not a complete list of emails, but a list of operations they performed upon it:

```
POST /{id}/changes
{
    "idempotency_token": <random string>,
    "revision": 123,
    "actions": [
        /* a list of actions */
    ]
}
```

(You may use `PATCH` if you want to, it's semantically correct here — `PATCH` is a method for modifying non-idempotent operations.)
Finally, you need to write server code which does the follows:

1. Compares actual revision with the one client sent;
2. If revisions are the same — just apply the operations and generate new revision;
3. If revisions are the same — the server needs to extract all the operations applied to the list in between the revisions, and ‘rebase’ client request in a manner modern version control system do. For example, if client deletes record #3, but, unseen to him, another client inserted new record in the head of the list, then #4 must be deleted.
   Note the idempotency token, it must be used, because your operations are not idempotent. You may find detailed explanation here: https://twirl.github.io/The-API-Book/docs/API.en.html#chapter-11 (rule #9).

Frankly, I would rather just make it simple and forbid collaborative editing. That's extremely tricky thing, even if we talk about easiest things.